Pasting Value to First Available Cell in a Specific Column (Last Row + 1)
I'm having difficulty in pasting a value to the "next row".  Essentially, a line in the code clicks a location in an application, copying a value to the clipboard.  I then want to paste that value into the next available cell in column C.  I know how to structure VBA code to do this in Excel, but I cannot seem to locate anything online that specifically calls out how to do this with python.
import xlwings as xlw
import pyautogui as pyauto
import pyperclip as pyclip

wbmd = xlw.Book('Member_Details.xlsx')
md_info = wbmd.sheets["Member_Info"]
mdlr = md_info.cells(md_info.cells.last_cell.row,1).end('up').row 

pyauto.PAUSE = 0.5

#Click on Member Name to Copy
pyauto.moveTo(x=2360, y=60)
pyauto.click(x=2360, y=60)     #Copies a value to the clipboard.

#Paste to Member Details/Member Info Column C Last Row + 1
md_info.range("C{mdlr + 1}").value = pyclip.paste()


Don't think this would point to a cell; md_info.range("C{mdlr + 1}").value Maybe it should be an f string?

That was it.  I noticed a lot of the responses had the f in front of some verbiage, but I was struggling to find something that explained what the f is and does.  Thank you very much!!!!
